# How to write abstract and acknowledgement in book format?

Tags: books, book-design, abstract, acknowledgements

I need to use this: `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}`

I have a main.tex file that organizes all the chapters. There is `\frontmatter`. In the frontmatter, there is

```
    \include{acknowledgement }
    \include{abstract}
    \include{dedication}
```

So, I created 3 files with this name. It kind of works. **BUT** it does not look like real abstract, ack... or dedication page.

I tried similar to

```
    \begin{abstract}
    My text
    \end{abstract}
```

It did not work. Can you please point me, how to add, abstract, dedication, acknowledgment?

Comment: Please add some information as to what you mean by it does not look like a real abstract. Preferably as a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.  This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

I took the liberty to format you post a little. See [this link for more details on available formatting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: You should say `\chapter{abstract}` in the abstract file  at the start and then `\include{abstract}`

Comment: What does the contents of `abstract.tex` look like? And what do you want the output to look like since a "real abstract" may be subjective?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few weeks ago I tried to add a dedication and an abstract to my book-document and this is what I found on the net and adapted:

dedication.tex

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \null\vspace{\stretch {1}}
        \begin{flushright}
                This is the Dedication.
        \end{flushright}
\vspace{\stretch{2}}\null
```

abstract.tex

```
\newenvironment{abstract}%
    {\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\vfill\begin{center}%
    \bfseries\abstractname\end{center}}%
    {\vfill\null}
        \begin{abstract}
        This is the abstract.
        \end{abstract}
```

acknowledgements.tex

```
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}%
    {\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\vfill\begin{center}%
    \bfseries Acknowledgements\end{center}}%
    {\vfill\null}
        \begin{acknowledgements}
        These are the acknowledgements.
        \end{acknowledgements}
```

main-file.tex

```
\frontmatter
    \include{content/frontmatter/titlepage}
    \include{content/frontmatter/dedication}
    \include{content/frontmatter/abstract}
    \include{content/frontmatter/acknowledgements}
    \include{content/frontmatter/preface}
    \tableofcontents
        ... and so on ...
```

Answer (score 9):

I'd simply do

```
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Abstract}

<text of the abstract>


\chapter{Acknowledgment}

<text of the acknowledgment>

\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\begin{flushright}
\itshape
Dedicated to my cat\\
and my dog
\end{flushright}
\vspace{\stretch{3}}
\cleardoublepage

\mainmatter
...
```

If you load the `emptypage` package, pages with no text added by explicit or implicit `\cleardoublepage` commands will be empty.

Note that there is no need to use `\chapter*` in the `\frontmatter`: it's instead *better* to use `\chapter`, because the entries will automatically go in the table of contents.

I'd not put the dedication in the table of contents, but feel free to do it with `\addcontentsline`.

If you want to use different files and `\include`, do it: it doesn't make any difference (but remember that `\include` always issues a `\clearpage` command).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when typing up my thesis. I read a few possible work-arounds and ended up with this one. First of all I'm used to not having abstract and acknowledgments in toc, but my solution can be tweaked to accommodate this wish with `\addcontentsline`.

To use this solution simply copy the two .sty-files below into an empty text-file and save them as `bookabstract.sty` and `acknowledgments.sty` in the same folder as your .tex-file and load them with `\usepackage{bookabstract}` and `\usepackage{acknowledgments}`. Then it's straight forward with `\begin{abstract}`, `\end{abstract}`, `\begin{acknowledgments}` and `\end{acknowledgments}`.

Here's what I did: First I made a two new .sty-files. One called `bookabstract.sty` and one called `acknowledgments.sty` (I should stress that these are not of my own making. I'm much obliged to whoever it was that posted this abstract-definition on another forum.) The only differences between them is that everywhere `bookabstracts.sty` contains the word "abstract" `acknowledgments.sty` contains the word "acknowledgments", and `acknowledgments.sty` contains a line defining `\acknowledgmentsname`. My thesis has two abstracts, one in English and one in Norwegian, so instead of defining `\abstractname` in the `bookabstract.sty`, I simply loaded babel with `\usepackage[british,norsk]{babel}` and used `\selectlanguage`. `\abstractname` is defined in babel, so this way my English abstract is called "Abstract" and my Norwegian abstract is called "Sammendrag" (which, as you may have guessed, is Norwegian for abstract). If you do not want to use babel, then you can simply define the `\abstractname` in the .sty-file.

Here is my `bookabstract.sty`:

```
%% Remember to load babel before loading this package or define the command \abstractname!
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother
```

And this is my `acknowledgments.sty`:

```
\newcommand\acknowledgmentsname{Acknowledgments}  %%copy this to the other package if you don't want to use babel (replace Acknowledgments with Abstract).
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{acknowledgments}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \acknowledgmentsname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{acknowledgments}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\acknowledgmentsname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \acknowledgmentsname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother
```