# Clash between alltt and semantic and minus sign

Tags: packages, incompatibility

Why does this code...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{semantic}
\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
\(x-y\)
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

...give this error?

> ERROR: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is an endless loop between the math ligature definition of `semantic` and the handling of `\( ...\)` of package `alltt`. Use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{semantic}
\begin{document}
\mathligsoff%%   <======
\begin{alltt}
   \(x-y\)
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ha! Nice detective work there, Herbert. `:)`

Comment: What if I *do* want ligatures inside the `alltt` environment?