# Abstract for thesis

Tags: abstract

Below is the preamble I used. After reading several pages I added abstract but it can't produce abstract my `.pdf` file.

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Declaration}\\
\end{center}
%\section*{Abstract}
\begin{Abstract}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\end{Abstract}
```

Now the error message appears is which is very common type:

```
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.33 \begin{Abstract}
```

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable!

Comment: Sorry I didn't got your point. Please rephrase it.

Comment: See here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/103046

Comment: In your code snippet `\end{abstact}` and `\end{document}` at last is missing. To help you show us a complete code resulting in the error you have ...

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100729/82917, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68222/82917, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51483/82917. The `book` class does not provide an environment for the abstract.

Comment: @campa: what should I write instead of book class? I am writing thesis.

Comment: Just use \chapter*{Abstract}.

Comment: @Johnnes: It worked

Comment: @Johannes: what should I do to give page number as well to the abstract page in list of contents page?

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}`. You could also download [unnumberedtotoc](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc/) and use `\addchap{Abstract}` instead. But if you need only one unnumbered chapter, the above line will be just fine. If the header annoys you, add `\markboth{Abstract}{Abstract}` as well (both directly after `\chapter*{Abst}`.